# How to remove default marker pop-up info-window

Tags: android-studio, google-maps, openstreetmap

I'm building a mapping app using the OpenStreetMap API. When I add a `Marker` object `myMarker` (green dot in the picture) as an overlay to the map, in default an (empty) info-window pops up when you tap on the object. I don't want this to happen.

I tried de-activating this popping up by entering `myMarker.setInfoWindow(null)`, but that didn't fix it. Please your advice.

[image]

Comment: `marker.infowindow.close();` does this work?

Comment: No, it didn't. Code not recognized. But you gave me an idea. In the onClickListener of myMarker I entered as first line InfoWindow.closeAllInfoWindowsOn(myMap). It's a hack, but it works! thanks.

Comment: Are you decide this problem? I have a same

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using hideInfowindow() method and returning true.

For Google Maps:

```
public void onMapReady(@NonNull GoogleMap googleMap) {
    map = googleMap;
    map.setOnMarkerClickListener(marker -> {
        marker.hideInfoWindow();
        //return true instead of false
        return true;
    });
}
```

For OpenStreetMap when map is loaded:

```
    mapObject.setOnMarkerClickListener(marker -> {
        marker.hideInfoWindow();
        //return true instead of false
        return true;
    });
```